# Is inversion of control implemented in Django?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I come from a .net background and I used to work with asp.net MVC that implemented dependency injection using UnityContainer, that did the mappings between the interfaces and their implementation. Now I am working with django and I wonder if there is something similar ?

Comment: Since most Django folks won't have extensive knowledge of ASP, you might want to give a more detailed explanation of what exactly you want to achieve, and where in your code you want to apply inversion of control. Since Python does not use interfaces but relies on [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Comment: The concepts of inversion of control and dependency injection are not language-specific; you can apply those in any language. What I think you're really asking, though, is does Django support actual DI containers, such that you can employ IoC at the framework-level. In that respect, I don't believe so.

Comment: Chris Pratt yes am asking if Django supports DI containers